# Batch processing of large number of data set Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, parallel-processing, queue

I currently have a Cron in laravel which takes data in chunk and call an API.

The flow is below

```
1. Cron runs every 5 minutes
2. Takes 80 data in chunks
3. Loop it through and call an API for 80 times and takes the next 80 in the next cron cycle
```

This method is so slow that if there are 10000000 records in the table it would take that many times to processes it. I have earlier used a chunk of 1000 which was breaking my system saying "Too many open files" exception for which I have reduced the chunk from 1000 to 80.

I know this a very bad design of what I am doing.

I need to re architect the current model and build something which can process in parallel. Atleast 500-1000 parallel processing of data.

How do I do that in Laravel. Is it even possible through PHP or do I have to look at an option like nodejs ? Please help me if its possible to use a queue. Even if I use queue will I be able to do parallel processing through it ?

**Update**

Now I have tried using Laravel queues

The command running in the background

```
php /Users/ajeesh/PhpstormProjects/untitled3/open-backend-v2/artisan queue:work database --tries=1 --timeout=56
```

My jobs are getting processed 3 times. I can't figure out why.

can someone suggest a solution here for this ?

Comment: Call an API 80 times?

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using ? and Can you explain why are you call too many API after every five minute ?

Comment: The jobs are running 3 times, that comes because of the job is failing. A failed job will (by default) run 3 times. Can you verify if the job fails (by looking at the output of queue:work)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run parallel jobs you will need to install a manager, like "Supervisor", that will provide various workers (instances) for you. You can set as many workers as your server resources can handle.

Keep in mind that each worker is a different instance of your laravel application, reflecting it's state at the time it was created. If you made changes to relevant code, like code for the job, you'll need to restart the supervisor, so it can get the newer version.

[Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration)

Next, you'll have to set a way for each job dispatched to require the correct available chunk.

Job 1 will get chunk 1 to 80.
Job 2 will get chunk 81 to 160.
...

You haven't detailed your code, maybe this will not be a problem, but if it is you can create a database table to track the chunks available and chunks not yet processed.

Regarding you job being fired 3 times, the code below:

```
php /Users/ajeesh/PhpstormProjects/untitled3/open-backend-v2/artisan queue:work database --tries=1 --timeout=56
```

It's function is to dispatch jobs already in the queue. Maybe another piece of code is queuing the job 3 times?

You won't need to manually dispatch jobs once you install "Supervisor". It will keep track of your jobs and dispatch'em as soon as they arrive (if you configured them that way).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of key questions that you must answer before we can come up with the best solution:

1. Are these API calls independent? If the calls depend on each other, then parallel processing is not possible. An example: say you're sifting through pages and the API call provides the URL of the next page in the previous call, then they're dependent calls and unless there's a pattern in there, you cant use parallel processing.
2. Why does the job call an API so many times? Is there an alternative (such as a bulk action API)?
3. You mentioned in your question about a table. Do you go through a table and for every record perform an API call?

Your jobs are probably getting called 3 times because they're failing from timeouts and you've set the number of trials to 3. If you have a `failed_jobs` table setup, check it out to see the error (I'm guessing timeout).

There are several solutions to these problems. Queues, process workers, a combination, etc. are possible solutions but each one has to be dealt with caution. The better way is to minimize the API calls (if possible). Will update the answer once you respond.